# QuickFIX/n MarketDataRequest duplicate tag 267 issue c#

Tags: c#, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I have added the debug pictures for visibility. The issue is that when I am to add NoMDEntryTypesGroup, it automaticly adds the 267 tag. Normally I want to add 267 but it adds value 1 as well.

First state of message before adding the NoMDEntryTypesGroup
[image: First state of message before adding the NoMDEntryTypesGroup]

NoMDEntryTypesGroup is prepared and in the picture you can see there are only 2 fields filled.
[image]

After adding the group now we have 267=1 even though we dont want it. How did it come? Is there way to prevent this?[image]

Finally we have the error as we were expecting.
[image]

So in summary I want to get rid of that 267=1 tag and just leave 267=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I found that adding Bid and Ask request automaticly puts that tag.No need to add specially.

```
        QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup group1 = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup();
        group1.Set(new MDEntryType('0'));
        message.AddGroup(group1);

        QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup group2 = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup();
        group2.Set(new MDEntryType('1'));
        message.AddGroup(group2);
```